# Prove that a given equation has two real roots

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(x) = e^x(x^2 - 5x + 7)$.

Prove that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ the equation $f^{(n)}(x) = 0$ has two real roots, where $f^{(n)}(x)$ represents the n-th degree derivative of $f$.

So far, I've found that $f^{(n)}(x)$ has the following form:
$$f^{(n)}(x) = e^x(x^2 + a_nx + b_n)$$
$$a_0 = -5, a_{n + 1} = a_n + 2$$
$$b_0 = 7, b_{n + 1} = b_n + a_n$$

In order to have two real roots, the discriminant of the equation must be strictly greater than $0$. 
$$a_n^2 - 4b_n > 0$$

At this point I have no idea how to proceed. If you have any ideas, please help me!

Thank you!

Comment: It seems unconventional to call the linear coefficient of a quadratic $a_n$ and the constant term $b_n$.  Wouldn't you rather call them $b_n$ and $c_n$?  Not that this helps your solution, just sayin'.

Comment: As for your solution, you have $a_n$ and $b_n$ defined recursively.  So maybe induction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $a_k^2 - 4b_k > 0$. We are now interested in $a^2_{k+1} - 4b_{k+1}$. We have
$$
a^2_{k+1} - 4b_{k+1} = (a_k + 2)^2 - 4(b_k + a_k)\\
= a_k^2 + 4a_k + 4 - 4b_k-4a_k\\
= a_k^2 - 4b_k + 4 > a_k^2 - 4b_k > 0
$$
which by induction gives that the polynomial always has two real roots.